# How to get the attributes from an Oracle global_context via package

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

For an Oracle Database session-based application context, I can find the attributes and values of the current session either in the view `session_context` or via the `dbms_session.list_context` package procedure.

For a global accessed context, this sources are always empty.

With the database view `global_context` I can query the attributes and values for my actual session.

Is there a package procedure similar then `dbms_session.list_context` to get the attributes and values in form of a pl/sql table?

Regards and thanks in advance